# sudo apt install ros-foxy-turtlebot3* dont download models for simulation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running on Ubuntu 20.04 Focal using ROS Foxy.

Following the tutorial on navigation stack (https://navigation.ros.org/getting_started/index.html), one step is to enter the command:  sudo apt install ros-foxy-turtlebot3*

It seems I cant download turtlebot3 models for simulation. As a result, gazebo shows an empty world without the turtlebot.

Also checked the share folder used in the command GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:/opt/ros/foxy/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models but could not find it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361813/sudo-apt-install-ros-foxy-turtlebot3*-dont-download-models-for-simulation/) by [PLui](https://answers.ros.org/users/59240/plui/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2020-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got this problem solved by following the instruction on this link (https://ubuntu.com/blog/simulate-the-turtlebot3).

After cloning the turtlebot3 repo and build the turtlebot3_ws using colcon, I added it to the GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH and ran the simulation.

---

Originally posted by [PLui](https://answers.ros.org/users/59240/plui/) with karma: 18 on 2020-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0